# Google Analytics Code Reporting as Receiving Data, But Not Reporting In Real Tim

Tags: google-analytics

I am working with my company to work on recieving data for individual ids through google analytics. We updated the code today to this:

GA says that it is receiving data, but I am not getting any visits in real time. This leads me to think that it is not receiving data since the update has been in there for 24 hours.

```
                    <script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-UA-45517330-1']);

// set custom variables
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Member", "yes", 1]);

// track page view
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;   i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;       m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com /analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-45517330-1', 'orchardsoft.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga(‘set’, ‘&uid’, {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
</script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Ho did you set "USER_ID" in you code? Is it server side or client side?

Comment: Is that the exact code as it appears on your site? There are multiple issues I have noticed. 1) Your "UA" string is incorrect - you have "UA-UA-....". 2) You should not have both GA and UA codes tracking at the same time. 3) You should not use "smart quotes" on the second last line for setting the User ID. 4) Also, looks like your site, orchardsoft.com, is down too.

Answer (score 0):

The 'set' instruction (s) must be declared before 'send'
Also you appear to be using both code versions: ga.js and analytics.js (preferred)